# Bootstrap does not work on SharePoint 2010 Internet explorer 8

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, content-editor-web-part, boot-strap

I need to support legacy internet explorer I.E. 8 applications. But Bootstrap does not work on the SharePoint 2010 page.
 I am injecting custom html using a content editor web part it works perfectly on all other browsers like chrome and firefox but on I.E 8 each column is displayed as a row. 
The HTML is as follows

`<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`

The script reference is as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Is there a fix for Bootstrap so that it can render in Internet explore 8 properly.

The current issue is that the columns render in separate rows instead of using the bootstrap css and js and render in the rows based on the bootstrap classes. It seems like it is ignoring Bootstrap.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, your problem is that IE8 does not support media queries.
Luckily, including the respond.js library should fix your problem!

```
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3